# How can I pass a collection of objects from VB6 to .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb6, interop, com-interop

I need to pass a collection of key/value pairs of strings from VB6 to .NET.  In VB6 code they exist in a native collection.  But I am not sure what I can reference in my .NET project to be able to accept a parameter of type Collection in one of my methods.

I tried adding a reference to Visual Basic for Applications but got back "A reference to 'Visual Basic For Applications' could not be added."

Am I going about it the wrong way?

Answer (score 4):

You could use something like this in c#:

```
[Guid("fb5e929a-2f8b-481e-9516-97edf5099df4")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface myInterface{
public void addObject(string key, string value);
}
```

And in your class, you could have this:

```
private collection
public addObject(string key, string value)
{
collection.Add(key, value);
}
```

This should allow you to call addObject in vb6 and passing your data. Then .net will add it to a collection, so instead of passing your whole collection from vb6 to .net, you pass them one by one.

You can read more about the [GUID here.](http://www.guidgenerator.com/online-guid-generator.aspx)

More info about COM with an exemple of code between [vb6 and c# here.](http://www.vbtonet.com/user-guide-appendix/add-com/)

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model), I have found it far simpler to just serialize my data as [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) and send it over the Interop chasm as plain text. I resisted it at first, but it is now my go-to solution. Give it a try if the "proper" solutions prove frustrating.

Comment: The collection is just a small piece of the puzzle. If I start writing serializing code for the entire object structure, we'll have .NET 9 out.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing it to [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) by making a `HashTable` in Visual Basic 6.0:

```
Set dictionary = Server.CreateObject("System.Collections.HashTable")
With dictionary
    For i = 1 To 100
        .Add Chr(i), "some text value"
    Next
End With
```

Then in a C# or [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) exposed class

```
public string LoadHashTable(Object tDict)
{
   return String.Format("Type : \"{0}\", Count : {1}", ((Hashtable)tDict).GetType().ToString(), ((Hashtable)tDict).Count);
}
```

An example of a COM exposed class is in Stack Overflow question *[Building a COM interop library for ASP Classic using 4.0 framework and Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923350)*

Remember to register it in both x86 and x64:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm MyThing.dll /tlb:MyThing.tlb /codebase MyThing

%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regasm MyThing.dll /tlb:MyThing.tlb /codebase MyThing
```

Comment: Why would I need to register it for x64?  VB6 is 32 bit only?

Comment: I am coming from a classic ASP background so I just reminded you to do both if required. VB6 exes you will only need 32 bit you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Your VB6 function can return a Dictionary from the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library. In .NET, you could add a COM reference to it. I found it useful to convert it to a System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary. I created a generic extension to do so allowing me to specify the type for the keys and values.

```
        public static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> ToDictionary<TKey, TValue>(this Scripting.Dictionary p_ScriptingDictionary)
    {
        string codeName = m_ModuleName + "." + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + "()";

        try
        {
            var dic = p_ScriptingDictionary.Cast<object>().ToDictionary(
                keySelector: elm => (TKey)elm,
                elementSelector: elm => (TValue)p_ScriptingDictionary.get_Item(ref elm));
            return dic;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Error converting Scripting.Dictionary to Systems.Collections.Generic.Dictionary.", ex);
        }
    }
```