# How to use features from an ASP.NET MVC application in an old ASP/VB script (ComVisible)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp-classic

I have created a new C# ASP.NET MVC application (for example `MyNewNetMVC`), which is integrated into IIS via `web.config` (as EXE).

I need to use part of the functionality of this MVC application in an old application written in ASP/VB, specifically methods of the `ASPService` class. I have read about .NET libraries using `ComVisible`. I don't know how to integrate `ComVisible` into my `MyNewNetMVC` application.

Or should I go the way of a second .NET project that will only provide functionality for the old ASP/VB?

How to use existing classes (`ASPService`) from the ASP.NET MVC application in this project? I need to call something like

```
Server.CreateObject("MyNewNetMVC.ASPService")
```

in the old ASP/VB application and then use the methods of the `ASPService` class to get the data. Thank you for your advice.

PS: [Building a COM interop library for ASP Classic using 4.0 framework and Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923350/building-a-com-interop-library-for-asp-classic-using-4-0-framework-and-visual-st) is not a solution :-(

Comment: Never been in a situation like this, but I am sure that you should forget about all this COM stuff. Try to reach your controller with simple requests from the ASP side. You can start with a search like [calling MVC controller from ASP classic code](https://www.bing.com/search?q=call%20mvc%20controller%20from%20asp%20classic%20code&qs=n&sk=&form=BDKTKB&pc=BDT1&shash=&BDParam=0000&mkt=en-US)

Comment: Can you rewrite the old logic in c# instead? That way, you don't have to worry about maintaining deprecated code